# Model generation error using Entity Framework for HANA client

Tags: entity-framework-6, hana, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am relatively new to .net and am working on a POC project and trying to generate an ADO.Net Entity Data model using Entity Framework (v 6.1.3) in Visual Studio Professional 2013 and connecting to SAP HANA Database. I am using.Net Framework 4.5 and I have installed both HANA 32 Bit Client (Version 1.0.120.0, and 64 Bit Client (Version 1.0.120.0) on my Windows (64bit) desktop. I am following the tutorial at the [link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/7d5922eb50fb481a8d0dd51c4dd3e2b7.html).

In Visual Studio, in the Entity Data Model Wizard, I am able to create a new connection to the HANA DB and test it successfully in "Choose your Data Connection" window and when I click next, on the "Choose your version" window, I get the following error and unable to proceed.

**"Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action."**

I have tried downgrading the Entity Framework version to 5 and 4 , searched through numerous posts with no luck. I have also tried just installing just the 64 bit or 32 bit version of the Client but apparently both versions are required. I found a post on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831785/create-model-with-entity-framework-on-hana-client) that suggests these versions should work together. Does anyone know what the issue could be and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Hana Client version on the server and location the same?
I had the same problem, my solution was to have the same version on the Hana server and local!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out the version of `Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll` was `2.2.33.0`, not `1.0.120.0`. I changed `1.0.120.0` to `2.2.33.0` in App.config, and the problem disappeared.

So, check the client version.